SPL token deploy from scratch
SPL token repo
I want to deploy a SPL token from original repo, are there any deployment guide for this? Thanks.

I am going to assume that you are coming from an EVM-compatible chain.
To create a token, you interact with the SPL token program which is already deployed. No need to deploys a smart contract for that.
Here are some resources I'd recommend to get started

https://solana.com/developers/evm-to-svm

https://solana.com/developers/courses/tokens-and-nfts



Yes, I'm coming from an EVM-compatible chain. If I create my own SPL token program. Could my token work on defi protocols like default program?

You'd need to lobby defi protocols, wallets and explorers to support your token.  What would be the advantages as opposed to using the SPL/token-22 program?

Thank you, so if I want to custom my own token, use token 2022 program is better than create another token program, right.

yes. Check out the documentation and developer tutorials. Also, you might need to familiarise yourself with the original SPL token since token-22 is just an extension of it on a new program.
